# TwitterCore SSO Authentication Expiration

Tags: android, twitter-fabric

I've followed the Android Fabric documentation on the following page:

http://docs.fabric.io/android/twitter/authentication.html

After clicking the Twitter login button, I see the "authorise app" screen and I'm able to authenticate.

What the documentation isn't clear on, is what to do when I need to user Twitter to login again.

Does the TwitterSession data returned have an expiration time? Is there a way to authenticate with Twitter SSO without showing the "authorise app" screen the second time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this answer:

https://twittercommunity.com/t/fabric-for-android-log-in-user-programatically-and-check-for-log-in/36955

It looks like once the TwitterSession has expired, then `TwitterCore.getInstance().getSessionManager().getActiveSession()` will return `null`. So the next thing to do is to re-authenticate.

One caveat, I read somewhere if you're using Guest Authentication, `getActiveSession()` will throw an exception (about rate limiting or something). So you'd need to trap this exception and re-authenticate.

The code for Guest Authentication is slightly different:

http://docs.fabric.io/android/twitter/authentication.html#guest-authentication

Comment: TwitterCore.getInstance().getSessionManager().getActiveSession() always return me null even if I'm logged in the twitter application. Can you guide me please?

Comment: It's been a while since I've done this. Unfortunately, I don't have access to the code anymore, either. What data do you get in the callback after successfully logging in?